# 3D viewer for Craft CMS

Tags: plugin-development, templating, assets

I really like grabcad's 3D viewer feature where the user can rotate, zoom, explode the 3d model.

I am wondering about adding similar feature to showcase my 3d models on my website and use asset field for project entry to load store file address on the html and have the js framework that is capable to rendering interactive primitive 3D model to hook up the file to the engine to display 3d model.

My question for folks out there, is there js framework similiar to grabcad's viewer feature?

Answer (score 1):

I know a lot of 3D programs are going to use different file formats. And the viewers tend to vary quite a bit. What are you using?  If you can export to obj format, [three.js](https://manu.ninja/webgl-3d-model-viewer-using-three-js) seems popular.

There's also services that do the heavy lifting of embedding as well. (Kind of like Vimeo for models). Just did a little bit of searching, [SketchFab](https://sketchfab.com) seems interesting and they also offer a free plan. They accept a bunch of file formats plus an API which you could tap in Craft.

They also do [oEmbeds](http://oembed.com) so you could use something like [Embed Assets](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-embedded-assets) to hook into it.

Comment: I don't have viewers hook up yet but Solidworks can export my models to obj or step format which you mention three.js as ideal framework candidate to render the models.  I have limit programming knowledge and three.js look like deep learning curve to achieve what I am after. .